# How do I retarget to a Rigify rig?

Tags: rigify

When tutorials show you how to retarget a BVH or Mixamo to the Metarig is that just the ends of the tutorial to avoid using the Rigify rig because it cannot be done?

Is there a way to retarget to the rigify rig?

Comment: There is an addon called [Expy-Kit](https://github.com/pKrime/Expy-Kit). I haven't tried it but it might do what you looking for. https://youtu.be/qRmGyX64KcA

Comment: @Blunder I have been using it, with an iffy success rate, works with Mixamo but not every kind of rig that comes from Mixamo. Sometimes you have to align bones other times it only works if you don't, sometimes it doesn't work no matter what you do.